# SQL bulk copy C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, sqlbulkcopy

I have an ASP.NET application to insert an excel file as a bulk I have an Excel file containing 50,000 records. I am using SQLBulkCopy to insert it. I can insert it successfully from the development environment. but when I am calling it from the server it inserts only about 9000 rows. Does any help, please?

Comment: *it inserts only about 9000 rows* - and then does what?

Comment: Are you getting any errors or log outputs? We can't guess what's happening.

Comment: I mean that I am converting the excel sheet to the data table. and in the server, it seems that converts only first 9000 records to data table

Comment: Without seeing your code we cannot help